error We were not able to estimate gas on metamask with V3 Swap Router uniswap contract
I am trying to do an ether exchange with tokens using uniswap sdk. The steps I am doing are as follows:

Routing by alpha router sdk

Creating a transaction and using the calldata obtained from the alpha router

Send transaction to Metamask


The problem I am facing is that when I use the local network like foundry, the transaction is done correctly, but when I want to run the same operation on the mainet network, I get an error in Metasmek (we were not able to estimate gas. There might be an error in the contract and this transaction might fail).
The steps I did are as follows:
package.json file:
{
    "name": "routing",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "@ethersproject/experimental": "^5.6.0",
      "@types/node": "^16.7.13",
      "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
      "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
      "@uniswap/sdk-core": "^3.1.0",
      "@uniswap/smart-order-router": "^3.0.6",
      "@uniswap/v3-periphery": "^1.4.3",
      "@uniswap/v3-sdk": "^3.9.0",
      "@web3-react/coinbase-wallet": "^8.2.3",
      "@web3-react/core": "^8.2.3",
      "@web3-react/eip1193": "^8.2.2",
      "@web3-react/empty": "^8.2.2",
      "@web3-react/gnosis-safe": "^8.2.4",
      "@web3-react/injected-connector": "^6.0.7",
      "@web3-react/metamask": "^8.2.4",
      "@web3-react/network": "^8.2.3",
      "@web3-react/types": "^8.2.2",
      "@web3-react/url": "^8.2.2",
      "@web3-react/walletconnect": "^8.2.3",
      "@web3-react/walletconnect-v2": "^8.5.1",
      "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
      "ethers": "^5.7.2",
      "lodash": "^4.17.21",
      "react": "^18.2.0",
      "react-bootstrap-icons": "^1.11.4",
      "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
      "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
      "react-spinners": "^0.14.1",
      "socket.io-client": "^4.7.5",
      "typescript": "^4.4.2",
      "yarn": "^1.22.22"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "install:chain": "curl -L https://foundry.paradigm.xyz | bash && clear && echo $0 | exec && foundryup",
      "start:chain": "anvil --chain-id 1337 --fork-url"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
      ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
      "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
      ],
      "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
      ]
    }
  }

Getting a price quote and routing by alpha router:
import { ethers, BigNumber } from "ethers";
  import { TradeType, CurrencyAmount, Percent, Ether } from "@uniswap/sdk-core";
  import { AlphaRouter, ChainId, SwapOptionsSwapRouter02, SwapRoute, SwapType, } from "@uniswap/smart-order-router";
  import { getMainnetProvider } from "../providers";
  import { PairTokenType } from "../../contexts/UniswapContexts/UniswapContexts";

  export async function generateRouteEthToken(
    uniswapTokenOut,
    tokenInAmount,
    pairTokenType,
    account,
    slippageAmount,
    deadlineMinutes
  ): Promise<SwapRoute | null> {
    if (pairTokenType !== PairTokenType.EthToken) return;

    const router = new AlphaRouter({
      chainId: ChainId.MAINNET,
      provider: getMainnetProvider(),
    });

    const options: SwapOptionsSwapRouter02 = {
      recipient: account,
      slippageTolerance: slippageAmount ? new Percent(Number(slippageAmount), 10_000) : new Percent(100, 10_000),
      deadline: deadlineMinutes ? Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * Number(deadlineMinutes) : Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 5,
      type: SwapType.SWAP_ROUTER_02,
    };

    const amountIn = ethers.utils.parseEther(tokenInAmount);

    const currencyAmount = CurrencyAmount.fromRawAmount(
      Ether.onChain(ChainId.MAINNET),
      amountIn.toString()
    );

    const route = await router.route(
      currencyAmount,
      uniswapTokenOut,
      TradeType.EXACT_INPUT,
      options
    );

    
    if (!route || !route.methodParameters) {
      console.log('NOT FOUND ROUTE');
      return null
    }
    
    return route;
  }

Execute swap and send transaction to v3 swap router (0x68b3465833fb72A70ecDF485E0e4C7bD8665Fc45)
  import { SwapRoute } from "@uniswap/smart-order-router";
  import { sendTransactionWalletExtention } from "../swapFunctions";
  import { V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS } from "../constants";

  export async function executeTradeEthToken(
    route: SwapRoute,
    account,
    provider,
  ) {

    const transaction = {
      data: route.methodParameters?.calldata,
      to: V3_SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS,
      value: route?.methodParameters?.value,
      from: account
    };

    const result = await sendTransactionWalletExtention(
      provider.provider,
      transaction,
      provider
    );

    return result;
  }

Send transaction to Metamask I tested the transaction in two ways, both using max fee, max priority fee and gas limit, and without these items, I still had the error.
Without gas parameters :
export async function sendTransactionWalletExtention(
    provider,
    transaction,
    innerProvider = null
  ) {
    try {
    
      const trx = await provider?.request({
        method: "eth_sendTransaction",
        params: [ transaction],
      });

      const receipt = await provider.waitForTransaction(trx);

      if (receipt.status === 1) {
        return {
          TransactionState: TransactionState.Sent,
          receipt: receipt,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          TransactionState: TransactionState.Failed,
          receipt: receipt,
        };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return {
        TransactionState: TransactionState.Failed,
        receipt: null,
      };
    }
  }

with gas parameters :
export async function sendTransactionWalletExtention(
    provider,
    transaction,
    innerProvider = null
  ) {
    try {
    
      const trx = await provider?.request({
        method: "eth_sendTransaction",
        params: [await estimateGasFees(innerProvider, transaction)],
      
      });

      const receipt = await provider.waitForTransaction(trx);

      if (receipt.status === 1) {
        return {
          TransactionState: TransactionState.Sent,
          receipt: receipt,
        };
      } else {
        return {
          TransactionState: TransactionState.Failed,
          receipt: receipt,
        };
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
      return {
        TransactionState: TransactionState.Failed,
        receipt: null,
      };
    }
  }

  export function estimateGasFees(provider, tx) {
    return provider.estimateGas(tx).then(async (estimatedGas) => {
    
      const pendingBlock = await provider.getBlock("pending");
      const baseFee = pendingBlock.baseFeePerGas;
      const tip = ethers.utils.parseUnits("5", "gwei");
      const maxFeePerGas = baseFee.add(tip);

      const txRequest = {
        ...tx,
        gasLimit: toHex(estimatedGas),
        maxPriorityFeePerGas: tip.toHexString(),
        maxFeePerGas: toHex(maxFeePerGas),
      };

      return txRequest;
    });
  }

The image of my Metamask status is like this, any help is appreciated
(https://i.sstatic.net/TpuXPPNJ.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/btGmPrUr.png)
